# XML path - case insensitive

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

How to convert XML xpath as case insensitive?

```
XmlNodeList elements = mConfig.SelectNodes(path);
```

path can be - Config/Setting/Name or config/setting/name

Comment: Hope this article helps [Case-insensitive XPath in .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/shjin/archive/2005/07/22/442025.aspx)

Comment: That article refers to Case-insensitve comparison of __values__ in the xml not the case insensitive comparison of xml node names.

Answer (score 2):

XML is case sensitive,  hence a node with then name `Config` is does have the same name as the node `config`.  Hence XPath must also respect this.

If you feel you need to use case-insensitive XPaths such as this then you really need to go back to the source of the XML and ask, "why is this generating XML where two nodes have the same meaning same yet differ casing"?  Then fix that.